# removing or changing from the origin branch in git

Tags: git, github

Im trying to make a new repo and sync it to github. However it keeps pushing to my origin.

So far ive found this command. 
git remove rm origin 
But was given this error. 
Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'

Next i tried this. 
git remote origin (The url of the origin)
And was returned this error. 
No such remote 'origin'

Any thoughts on what to try next? thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Create your repo locally, make a commit if you feel necessary (`git init, git add --all, git commit -m "Initial"`)
2. Create your repo remotely, and save a link to you repository, for example: https://github.com/you/yourproject.git
3. If you have some old "origin", remove it: `git remote remove origin`
4. Add new origin: `git remote add origin https://github.com/you/yourproject.git`
5. Now you're done and free to push (`git push origin master`)

Comment: thank you, git remote remove origin is the correct answer. If anyone is new to terminal (like myself) when you put this command in and run git remote -v (to view the origin) if you see nothing, that is a good thing. meaning you can then add your new origin. thanks for your help!